# C# login system

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

Currently I'm experimenting how I can make a login system, with different userinput. (Every user has his own information).I've two database tables, one is called "user" (here is id primary key, and username and password are in it) and the second table is the "userInformation" (here is id the foreign key and there is information like name,adres etc.) I've made it like this:

```
  public partial class standardUserInterface : Form
{
    int userIdNumber;
    string[] userinfo;
    public standardUserInterface(int userIdNumber)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userinfo = new string[3];
        this.userIdNumber = userIdNumber;
        string selectUserData = "select voornaam,achternaam,woonplaats from dbo.usersinfo inner join dbo.loginuser on usersinfo.id=@loginUserId";
        SqlConnection conn = sqlConn.openSqlConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(selectUserData, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginUserId", userIdNumber);
        SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                userinfo[i] = dr.GetString(i);
            }
        }
        lblVoornaam.Text = userinfo[0];
        lblAchternaam.Text = userinfo[1];
        lblAdres.Text = userinfo[2];
    }
}
```

What do you think about this? Is there a better way, or is this done right?

EDIT

This is the login before it's receiving the userdata

```
  private string password;
    private string username;
    private int userIdNumber;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username = txtUsername.Text;
        password = txtPassword.Text;
        userLogin user = new userLogin(username, password);
        //wachtwoord & gebruikersnaam controleren
        if (username != "" & password != "")
        {
            if (user.checkPassword())
            {
                this.Hide();
                userIdNumber = user.checkID();
                standardUserInterface openUserInterface = new standardUserInterface(userIdNumber);
                openUserInterface.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wachtwoord is onjuist");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("vul alle velden in");
        }
    }
```

Comment: but what exactly you are trying to do with this

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for code reviews, but there's unfortunately a lot wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't we need a authentication system for log in, wherein we can validate the used id and password? only if the validation is successful we will go for fetching the user details

one suggestion, it will be better if we can create a stored procedure for getting the user data instead of the inline query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When the user is validated it will search for the users id and compare it with the id in table userInformation. Then it takes the userinformation and puts it in a textbox.

Comment: _"it will be better if we can create a stored procedure"_ - explain why you think this is the case.

Comment: The advantages can be found in the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've done it now (the stored procedure)`

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("searchForUserInformation", conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginUserId", userIdNumber);`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Registration 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Csharp_Login_And_Register
{
    public partial class RegisterForm : Form
    {
        public RegisterForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RegisterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // remove the focus from the textboxes
            this.ActiveControl = label1;
        }

        private void textBoxFirstname_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String fname = textBoxFirstname.Text;
            if(fname.ToLower().Trim().Equals("first name"))
            {
                textBoxFirstname.Text = "";
                textBoxFirstname.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxFirstname_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String fname = textBoxFirstname.Text;
            if (fname.ToLower().Trim().Equals("first name") || fname.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                textBoxFirstname.Text = "first name";
                textBoxFirstname.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxLastname_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String lname = textBoxLastname.Text;
            if (lname.ToLower().Trim().Equals("last name"))
            {
                textBoxLastname.Text = "";
                textBoxLastname.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxLastname_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String lname = textBoxLastname.Text;
            if (lname.ToLower().Trim().Equals("last name") || lname.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                textBoxLastname.Text = "last name";
                textBoxLastname.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxEmail_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String email = textBoxEmail.Text;
            if (email.ToLower().Trim().Equals("email address"))
            {
                textBoxEmail.Text = "";
                textBoxEmail.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxEmail_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String email = textBoxEmail.Text;
            if (email.ToLower().Trim().Equals("email address") || email.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                textBoxEmail.Text = "email address";
                textBoxEmail.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxUsername_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String username = textBoxUsername.Text;
            if (username.ToLower().Trim().Equals("username"))
            {
                textBoxUsername.Text = "";
                textBoxUsername.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxUsername_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String username = textBoxUsername.Text;
            if (username.ToLower().Trim().Equals("username") || username.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                textBoxUsername.Text = "username";
                textBoxUsername.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxPassword_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String password = textBoxPassword.Text;
            if (password.ToLower().Trim().Equals("password"))
            {
                textBoxPassword.Text = "";
                textBoxPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
                textBoxPassword.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxPassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String password = textBoxPassword.Text;
            if (password.ToLower().Trim().Equals("password") || password.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                textBoxPassword.Text = "password";
                textBoxPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
                textBoxPassword.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxPasswordConfirm_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String cpassword = textBoxPasswordConfirm.Text;
            if (cpassword.ToLower().Trim().Equals("confirm password"))
            {
                textBoxPasswordConfirm.Text = "";
                textBoxPasswordConfirm.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
                textBoxPasswordConfirm.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxPasswordConfirm_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String cpassword = textBoxPasswordConfirm.Text;
            if (cpassword.ToLower().Trim().Equals("confirm password") ||
                cpassword.ToLower().Trim().Equals("password") ||
                cpassword.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                textBoxPasswordConfirm.Text = "confirm password";
                textBoxPasswordConfirm.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
                textBoxPasswordConfirm.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void labelClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }


        private void labelClose_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelClose.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }

        private void labelClose_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelClose.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void buttonCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // add a new user

            DB db = new DB();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `emailaddress`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (@fn, @ln, @email, @usn, @pass)", db.getConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxFirstname.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxLastname.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxEmail.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxUsername.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPassword.Text;

            // open the connection
            db.openConnection();

            // check if the textboxes contains the default values 
            if (!checkTextBoxesValues())
            {
                // check if the password equal the confirm password
                if(textBoxPassword.Text.Equals(textBoxPasswordConfirm.Text))
                {
                    // check if this username already exists
                    if (checkUsername())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This Username Already Exists, Select A Different One","Duplicate Username",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // execute the query
                        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Your Account Has Been Created","Account Created",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Confirmation Password","Password Error",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Informations First","Empty Data",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            
            

            // close the connection
            db.closeConnection();

        }

        
        // check if the username already exists
        public Boolean checkUsername()
        {
            DB db = new DB();

            String username = textBoxUsername.Text;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = @usn", db.getConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            adapter.Fill(table);

            // check if this username already exists in the database
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        // check if the textboxes contains the default values
        public Boolean checkTextBoxesValues()
        {
            String fname = textBoxFirstname.Text;
            String lname = textBoxLastname.Text;
            String email = textBoxEmail.Text;
            String uname = textBoxUsername.Text;
            String pass = textBoxPassword.Text;

            if(fname.Equals("first name") || lname.Equals("last name") || 
                email.Equals("email address") || uname.Equals("username")
                || pass.Equals("password"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            
        }

        private void labelGoToLogin_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelGoToLogin.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        }

        private void labelGoToLogin_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelGoToLogin.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void labelGoToLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            LoginForm loginform = new LoginForm();
            loginform.Show();
        }


    }
}

namespace Csharp_Login_And_Register
{
    partial class RegisterForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.labelGoToLogin = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBoxUsername = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBoxEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBoxLastname = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.buttonCreateAccount = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBoxPassword = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBoxFirstname = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.labelClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(17)))), ((int)(((byte)(24)))), ((int)(((byte)(34)))));
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.labelGoToLogin);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxPasswordConfirm);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxUsername);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxEmail);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxLastname);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.buttonCreateAccount);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxPassword);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxFirstname);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(635, 624);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // labelGoToLogin
            // 
            this.labelGoToLogin.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelGoToLogin.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.labelGoToLogin.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.labelGoToLogin.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.labelGoToLogin.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(238, 569);
            this.labelGoToLogin.Name = "labelGoToLogin";
            this.labelGoToLogin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(164, 13);
            this.labelGoToLogin.TabIndex = 201;
            this.labelGoToLogin.Text = "Already Have an Account? Login";
            this.labelGoToLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.labelGoToLogin_Click);
            this.labelGoToLogin.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.labelGoToLogin_MouseEnter);
            this.labelGoToLogin.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.labelGoToLogin_MouseLeave);
            // 
            // textBoxPasswordConfirm
            // 
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 388);
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Name = "textBoxPasswordConfirm";
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(537, 40);
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.TabIndex = 9;
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Text = "confirm password";
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxPasswordConfirm_Enter);
            this.textBoxPasswordConfirm.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxPasswordConfirm_Leave);
            // 
            // textBoxUsername
            // 
            this.textBoxUsername.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxUsername.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.textBoxUsername.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 264);
            this.textBoxUsername.Multiline = true;
            this.textBoxUsername.Name = "textBoxUsername";
            this.textBoxUsername.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(537, 40);
            this.textBoxUsername.TabIndex = 8;
            this.textBoxUsername.Text = "username";
            this.textBoxUsername.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxUsername_Enter);
            this.textBoxUsername.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxUsername_Leave);
            // 
            // textBoxEmail
            // 
            this.textBoxEmail.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxEmail.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.textBoxEmail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 204);
            this.textBoxEmail.Multiline = true;
            this.textBoxEmail.Name = "textBoxEmail";
            this.textBoxEmail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(537, 40);
            this.textBoxEmail.TabIndex = 7;
            this.textBoxEmail.Text = "email address";
            this.textBoxEmail.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxEmail_Enter);
            this.textBoxEmail.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxEmail_Leave);
            // 
            // textBoxLastname
            // 
            this.textBoxLastname.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxLastname.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.textBoxLastname.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(329, 145);
            this.textBoxLastname.Multiline = true;
            this.textBoxLastname.Name = "textBoxLastname";
            this.textBoxLastname.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 40);
            this.textBoxLastname.TabIndex = 6;
            this.textBoxLastname.Text = "last name";
            this.textBoxLastname.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxLastname_Enter);
            this.textBoxLastname.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxLastname_Leave);
            // 
            // buttonCreateAccount
            // 
            this.buttonCreateAccount.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(217)))), ((int)(((byte)(66)))), ((int)(((byte)(85)))));
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.buttonCreateAccount.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.buttonCreateAccount.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.buttonCreateAccount.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 473);
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Name = "buttonCreateAccount";
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(537, 60);
            this.buttonCreateAccount.TabIndex = 5;
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Text = "CREATE ACCOUNT";
            this.buttonCreateAccount.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.buttonCreateAccount.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonCreateAccount_Click);
            // 
            // textBoxPassword
            // 
            this.textBoxPassword.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxPassword.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.textBoxPassword.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 325);
            this.textBoxPassword.Name = "textBoxPassword";
            this.textBoxPassword.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(537, 40);
            this.textBoxPassword.TabIndex = 4;
            this.textBoxPassword.Text = "password";
            this.textBoxPassword.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxPassword_Enter);
            this.textBoxPassword.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxPassword_Leave);
            // 
            // textBoxFirstname
            // 
            this.textBoxFirstname.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxFirstname.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.textBoxFirstname.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 145);
            this.textBoxFirstname.Multiline = true;
            this.textBoxFirstname.Name = "textBoxFirstname";
            this.textBoxFirstname.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 40);
            this.textBoxFirstname.TabIndex = 200;
            this.textBoxFirstname.Text = "first name";
            this.textBoxFirstname.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxFirstname_Enter);
            this.textBoxFirstname.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxFirstname_Leave);
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(183)))), ((int)(((byte)(19)))));
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.labelClose);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-6, 0);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(641, 93);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // labelClose
            // 
            this.labelClose.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelClose.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.labelClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.labelClose.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.labelClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(615, 3);
            this.labelClose.Name = "labelClose";
            this.labelClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 22);
            this.labelClose.TabIndex = 1;
            this.labelClose.Text = "X";
            this.labelClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClose_Click);
            this.labelClose.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClose_MouseEnter);
            this.labelClose.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClose_MouseLeave);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 27.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(641, 93);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // RegisterForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(635, 624);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "RegisterForm";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "RegisterForm";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.RegisterForm_Load);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel2.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonCreateAccount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxPassword;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxFirstname;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelClose;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxPasswordConfirm;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxUsername;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxEmail;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxLastname;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelGoToLogin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace Csharp_Login_And_Register
    {
        public partial class LoginForm : Form
        {
            
            public LoginForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                this.textBoxPassword.AutoSize = false;
                this.textBoxPassword.Size = new Size(this.textBoxPassword.Size.Width, 50);
            }
    
            private void labelClose_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                labelClose.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
    
            private void labelClose_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                labelClose.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
    
            private void labelClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //this.Close();
                Application.Exit();
            }
    
            private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DB db = new DB();
    
                String username = textBoxUsername.Text;
                String password = textBoxPassword.Text;
    
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
    
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = @usn and `password` = @pass", db.getConnection());
    
                command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
                command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
    
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    
                adapter.Fill(table);
    
                // check if the user exists or not
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
                    mainform.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(username.Trim().Equals(""))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Username To Login","Empty Username",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else if (password.Trim().Equals(""))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Password To Login", "Empty Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username Or Password", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
    
            }
    
            private void labelGoToSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                RegisterForm registerform = new RegisterForm();
                registerform.Show();
            }
    
            private void labelGoToSignUp_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                labelGoToSignUp.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
    
            private void labelGoToSignUp_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                labelGoToSignUp.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
    
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    
    namespace Csharp_Login_And_Register
    {
        /*
             we need to download the mysql connector
             * add the connector to our project
             * ( watch the video to see how ) 
             * create a connection now with mysql
             * open xampp and start mysql & apache
             * go to phpmyadmin and create the users database
             */
    
        class DB
        {
    
           private MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=csharp_users_db");
    
    
            // create a function to open the connection
            public void openConnection()
            {
                if(connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
            }
    
            // create a function to close the connection
            public void closeConnection()
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
    
            // create a function to return the connection
            public MySqlConnection getConnection()
            {
                return connection;
            }
        }
    }


namespace Csharp_Login_And_Register
{
    partial class LoginForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.labelGoToSignUp = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.buttonLogin = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBoxPassword = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.textBoxUsername = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.labelClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(17)))), ((int)(((byte)(24)))), ((int)(((byte)(34)))));
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.labelGoToSignUp);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.buttonLogin);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxPassword);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBoxUsername);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 523);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // labelGoToSignUp
            // 
            this.labelGoToSignUp.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.labelGoToSignUp.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(195, 479);
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Name = "labelGoToSignUp";
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(211, 17);
            this.labelGoToSignUp.TabIndex = 6;
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Text = "Don\'t Have an Account? SignUp";
            this.labelGoToSignUp.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.labelGoToSignUp_Click);
            this.labelGoToSignUp.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.labelGoToSignUp_MouseEnter);
            this.labelGoToSignUp.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.labelGoToSignUp_MouseLeave);
            // 
            // buttonLogin
            // 
            this.buttonLogin.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(242)))), ((int)(((byte)(103)))), ((int)(((byte)(46)))));
            this.buttonLogin.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.buttonLogin.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.buttonLogin.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.buttonLogin.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.buttonLogin.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.buttonLogin.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 380);
            this.buttonLogin.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.buttonLogin.Name = "buttonLogin";
            this.buttonLogin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(541, 74);
            this.buttonLogin.TabIndex = 5;
            this.buttonLogin.Text = "LOGIN";
            this.buttonLogin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.buttonLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonLogin_Click);
            // 
            // textBoxPassword
            // 
            this.textBoxPassword.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxPassword.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 276);
            this.textBoxPassword.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.textBoxPassword.Name = "textBoxPassword";
            this.textBoxPassword.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 53);
            this.textBoxPassword.TabIndex = 4;
            this.textBoxPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.Image = global::Csharp_Login_And_Register.Properties.Resources._lock;
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 276);
            this.pictureBox2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 62);
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // textBoxUsername
            // 
            this.textBoxUsername.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxUsername.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 178);
            this.textBoxUsername.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.textBoxUsername.Multiline = true;
            this.textBoxUsername.Name = "textBoxUsername";
            this.textBoxUsername.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 61);
            this.textBoxUsername.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::Csharp_Login_And_Register.Properties.Resources.user;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 178);
            this.pictureBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 62);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(183)))), ((int)(((byte)(19)))));
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.labelClose);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-8, 0);
            this.panel2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 114);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // labelClose
            // 
            this.labelClose.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelClose.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.labelClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.labelClose.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.labelClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(604, 4);
            this.labelClose.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            this.labelClose.Name = "labelClose";
            this.labelClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 27);
            this.labelClose.TabIndex = 1;
            this.labelClose.Text = "X";
            this.labelClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClose_Click);
            this.labelClose.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClose_MouseEnter);
            this.labelClose.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClose_MouseLeave);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 27.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 114);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "USER LOGIN";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // LoginForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 523);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            this.Name = "LoginForm";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "LoginForm";
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel2.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelClose;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxPassword;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxUsername;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonLogin;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelGoToSignUp;
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Csharp_Login_And_Register
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```